# Changing input or select's value from serverside makes it unsync

Tags: asp.net, html

Before I explain, I must tell you that in my project I have to use HTML inputs and buttons (no asp controls).

I have a user editting page on my project where the values of the inputs and selects are set by the current data, and what should function is - setting the data to the newly edited data on the form.

However, **when I change the value from the serverside like this:**

```
tbEmail.Value = dTable.Rows[userIndex]["Email"].ToString();
```

(tbEmail is an input with the type of "text")

Then, when the administrator user edits information in the button **onserversideclick** event the script somewhat uses the pre-set values. If I comment these .Value setting lines, then it works fine (**but I want to make the functions edit and it's not comfortable to edit without knowing the current data**)

***THANKS IF YOU HELP***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I remember right my problem was not using IsPostBack method on page load. Answering just incase someone else runs into this stupid little problem.